# passing a object from an activity to an non activity class

Tags: android, object, android-activity

How can I pass an object from an activity to a non activity class on android? I tried to use an instance of that class, but when I use an object (from that class) I get `NullPointerException`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class IncercLaPauseActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout layout;
    TextView index;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagBackground);
        index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
        }
}
```

the xml file is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/photo0"
    android:id="@+id/imagBackground">

    <TextView android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/index" android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>
    <com.www.MyImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_below="@id/index">
    </com.www.MyImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and on non activity class I do something like this :

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    Paint rectanglePaint;
    int x, y,i=0;
    Rect tete, yeux, dos, abdomen, epaule1, epaule2, avant_bras1, avant_bras2,
            main1, main2, genoux, pieds, respiration;
    Bitmap bit;

    IncercLaPauseActivity obj;

    private int[] photos = { R.drawable.photo0, R.drawable.photo1,
            R.drawable.photo2, R.drawable.photo3, R.drawable.photo4,
            R.drawable.photo5, R.drawable.photo6, R.drawable.photo7,
            R.drawable.photo8, R.drawable.photo9, R.drawable.photo10,
            R.drawable.photo11, R.drawable.photo12, R.drawable.photo13,
            R.drawable.photo14, R.drawable.photo15, R.drawable.photo16,
            R.drawable.photo17, R.drawable.photo18, R.drawable.photo19,
            R.drawable.photo20, R.drawable.photo21, R.drawable.photo22 };

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        rectanglePaint = new Paint();
        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 255, 0, 0);
        tete = new Rect(220, 0, 280, 67);// in pixels

        yeux = new Rect(220, 4, 280, 20);

        epaule1 = new Rect(175, 75, 200, 197);
        epaule2 = new Rect(297, 75, 320, 197);

        avant_bras1 = new Rect(170, 200, 195, 300);// in pixels
        avant_bras2 = new Rect(300, 200, 325, 300);// in pixels

        main1 = new Rect(170, 303, 195, 345);
        main2 = new Rect(300, 303, 325, 345);

        respiration = new Rect(200, 75, 297, 177);
        abdomen = new Rect(202, 177, 290, 260);
        genoux = new Rect(200, 260, 297, 430);
        bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                   R.drawable.anim_ctrl_panel);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("draw");
        canvas.drawRect(tete, rectanglePaint);

        canvas.drawRect(epaule1, rectanglePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(epaule2, rectanglePaint);

        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 0, 255, 0);
        canvas.drawRect(avant_bras1, rectanglePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(avant_bras2, rectanglePaint);

        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(main1, rectanglePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(main2, rectanglePaint);

        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 0, 255, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(respiration, rectanglePaint);

        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 255, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(abdomen, rectanglePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(yeux, rectanglePaint);

        rectanglePaint.setARGB(120, 255, 255, 0);
        canvas.drawRect(genoux, rectanglePaint);


        canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 80, 410, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int) event.getX();
        System.out.println("x este " + x);
        y = (int) event.getY();
        System.out.println("y este " + y);
        if (avant_bras1.contains(x, y) || (avant_bras2.contains(x, y))) {
            System.out.println("antebrat");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this.getContext(), Selecter.class);
            this.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (event.getX() > bit.getWidth() / 2) {
            System.out.println("right");
            i++;
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
            if (i <= 22) {
                obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);
                obj.index.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            } else {
                i = 0;
                obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);
                obj.index.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }else {
            i--;
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
            if (i >= 0) {
                obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);
                obj.index.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            } else {
                i = 22;
                obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);
                obj.index.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("left");
        return false;
    }

}
```

and I get this error :

```
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at com.www.MyImageView.onTouchEvent(MyImageView.java:112)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:822)
10-21 17:34:42.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2011):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
```

where `line 112` is first line `obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);`

Comment: Please post your code that is causing the NullPointer to occur, this will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: you should pass it on the constructor of your Second Class , and make sure that you have instanciate your Object . add your code so we can help you to fix it :)

Comment: Agree with the above comments - post more code and be clear about what you are trying to do so we can best help you.

Comment: so where is the the error ?? add your stack trace plz,

Comment: the error is on line 112 , exaclty on the method onTouchEvent , what is on this line ??

Comment: obj.layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]); after if(i<=22)

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this :

on the onCreate method add this :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagBackground);
        index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
        //here pass your activity ( this ) to your second Class and instanciate it 
        YourSecondClass obj = new YourSecondClass(this);
        }
```

and in your second class , the constructor will be like this :

```
IncercLaPauseActivity context ; 

public YourSecondClass(IncercLaPauseActivity _context){
   this.context = _context;
   ....
}
```

**NB : you should never instanciate an Activity :),**

**EDIT :**

replace `obj.layout.setBakgroun..`.. with :

```
RelativeLayour layout = (RelativeLayout) this.getParent();

layout.setBackgroundResource(photo[i]);
```

Comment: but my second class extends ImageView and is set on xml file, and if I change the constructor like this, it will not work :|

Comment: i give you the answer in general , in your ex code , you instanciate your activity on the constructor of your second class, that's why it didnt work because you sould never instanciate an activity with new ... . if your second class is an imageView , so you should declare your imageView on the onCreate method , and pass the context to its constructor ( pass this ) .. add the full code of the both of classes plz

Comment: the error is on line 112 , exaclty on the method onTouchEvent , what is on this line ??

Comment: there is no methos setBackground() for getParent() ...so it not works

Comment: should I modify the constructor?

Comment: I modified as you said but the is no method setBackground() for getParent()...it results an error at that line

Comment: i said ,setBackgroundResource() ... :) ; just like in your code , the essential is to modify the obj.layout with : this.getParent()

Comment: what is the error that you have got ? see my edit and try again

Comment: now I get NullPointerException at line     layout.setBackgroundResource(photos[i]);

Answer (score 0):

**hi, the best way is create a object as**

> public class TestingA extends Activity {
>   ........................................
>
> ```
> public static Example objExml = new Example();
> ```
>
> ......................................... }

**and then accessing the object in another class as under**

```
public class TestingB extends Activity{

...................................
your code
................................

TestingA.objExml 

...............................

}
```